# "Highly" vs "Richly"

Tags: word-choice

Sentence:-

1. "I **highly/richly** deserve this honour."
2. "He **highly/richly** deserves this punishment."

According to my textbook 1. Ans: "*highly*"
2. Ans: "*richly*"

As both "*highly*" and "*richly*" conveys "to a large degree" how to decide which one to use?

Comment: Google's Ngram Viewer is useful tool in testing the popularity of such constructions. In this case, **richly** wins by several lengths.    https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=highly+deserve%2Crichly+deserve&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chighly%20deserve%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Crichly%20deserve%3B%2Cc0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Richly* does not generally mean *highly*. It is common in only two cases:

1. When it is referring, literally or figuratively, to something which appeals to the senses, most often vision: *richly decorated*, *richly textured*, *richly detailed*, *richly flavoured*.
2. With *deserved*. Treat this as an idiom.

I advise against using it in any other case.

Comment: Oops, apologies... The answer of the first one was "highly" and of the second one was "richly" I've edited now. Btw I got your point.